# Scroll with button to jump section

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to create a button in angular js that can allow me to jump to the next section dynamically like a html anchor but the link to jump follow user.

Solution will be simply i think, but i don't have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Use css `position: fixed` for the button styling and [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) to scroll.

Comment: i have already try to use $anchorScroll, but how i can detect i am after the div for change my link ?

Comment: After which div? Which link? What do you want to change it into?

Comment: After h1 of each div, if i click on arrow down, i go to the next h1

Comment: Not so easy then, because you need your button's scope to know where it is. If you could only scroll with the button it'd be easy (but I doubt it's the case) : you'd init a myPosition to 0, and each time you click the button increment it. The button would change the hash to the next section hash, which would have to be derived from its position (e.g. section1, derived from `"section" + (myPosition + 1)`)

Comment: An easy solution would be not to use a fixed button but rather have one for each section, that would point to the next section. You could possibly generate them in a `ng-repeat` if if bothers you to create and maintain them by hand

Answer (score 0):

you can also use angular-scroll:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/378d1810836c5a556a0f02b1e6b962bf?editors=1010)

[image: Image demo from codepen]

html

```
<!-- Add ref to script after angular, just before closing body tag-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/1.0.0/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
```

add id to target, then du-smooth-scroll directive to button

```
<p><a href="#followUser" du-smooth-scroll>Scroll to {{user.name.first}}</a></p>
<p>
   ...
</p>
<p><a id="followUser">Follow {{user.name.first}}</a></p>
```

js

```
// expose angular scroll to app
var module = angular.module('app',['duScroll']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not really what i search, i m try an other solution with height of page but i m a little lost

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly what i want but it seem work:

```
    $('.row-title').each(function(i,item){
        $(item).attr('id', 'scroll-id-'+i);
    });
var id=-1;
var scrollTop;
var tmp;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    tmp=id;
    scrollTop=$(this).scrollTop();

    $('.row-title').each(function(i,item){
        if(item.offsetTop >=scrollTop && id!=i){

            console.log(item.outerText);
            $('.scrollToDown').attr("href", '#scroll-id-'+i);
            id=i;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollToUp').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToUp').fadeOut();
    }
});
//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToDown').click(function(){
    if(id == tmp){
        tmp++;
        $('.scrollToDown').attr("href", '#scroll-id-'+tmp);
    }

});
//Click event to scroll to top
$('#scrollUpDown .up').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});
```